# Query to return consecutive record count

Tags: sql, oracle

Given this table `t`

```
  Date          Value
  15-Jan-2020   true 
  14-Jan-2020   true 
  13-Jan-2020   true 
  12-Jan-2020   false
  11-Jan-2020   true 
  10-Jan-2020   false
  09-Jan-2020   false
```

How can you write a query to return the number of previous consecutive days that have a value of `true`?

In this example this would be 3.

When querying this table the most recent record will always be `true`.  The records/dates prior to this can be true or false.  Thus the query would practically return values between 1 to n.

Comment: Do you really want a PL/SQL procedure/function or are you after an SQL query? PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language.

Comment: Whatever works :)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of well-known SQL tricks for this sort of thing.  I like using the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` feature.  I find it less arcane than other ways.  Try this:

```
with input ( d, v ) as
( 
  SELECT to_date('15-Jan-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'),'true' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT to_date('14-Jan-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'),'true' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT to_date('13-Jan-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'),'true' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT to_date('12-Jan-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'),'false' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT to_date('11-Jan-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'),'true' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT to_date('10-Jan-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'),'false' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT to_date('09-Jan-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'),'false ' FROM DUAL)
select d, v, cnt
from input
match_recognize (
  order by d
  measures running count(value_true.d) as cnt
  all rows per match
  pattern (value_true*)
  define 
    value_true AS value_true.v = 'true'
    )
order by d desc    
;
```

> ```
> +----------------------+--------+-----+
> |          D           |   V    | CNT |
> +----------------------+--------+-----+
> | 15-JAN-2020 00:00:00 | true   |   3 |
> | 14-JAN-2020 00:00:00 | true   |   2 |
> | 13-JAN-2020 00:00:00 | true   |   1 |
> | 12-JAN-2020 00:00:00 | false  |   0 |
> | 11-JAN-2020 00:00:00 | true   |   1 |
> | 10-JAN-2020 00:00:00 | false  |   0 |
> | 09-JAN-2020 00:00:00 | false  |   0 |
> +----------------------+--------+-----+
> ```

`MATCH_RECOGNIZE` looks for patterns among rows.  In this case, we give a pattern as follows:

```
pattern (value_true*)
```

which is find zero or more (that's the asterisk) "value_true" rows.  A row is "value_true" based on our definition:

```
define 
  value_true AS value_true.v = 'true'
```

We then tell Oracle, to compute a `COUNT()` of the number of rows that matched the pattern and call the result `cnt`.  Since, in our `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` was are sorting by the date in *ascending* order and since our `MEASURES` clause specified `RUNNING COUNT` (as opposed to `FINAL COUNT`), this is a count of "true" rows from the beginning of a group up to and including the current row.  That is, the number of consecutive prior "true" rows (if you count the current row).

Maybe "less arcane" wasn't the right way to put it.  I meant, maybe, "more explicit".  The syntax is less familiar, but it speaks to what you are doing: namely, looking for pattern of consecutive rows where `value = true` and counting them.

Comment: "I find it less arcane than other ways." Please add an explanation off what it is doing and why it works

Comment: @MT0 I added a walk-through.  I hope it makes sense.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Since your rows are consecutive dates, you can use the `LAG(...) IGNORE NULLS (...)` analytic function with a `CASE` expression to filter the rows to find the most recent `false` row (for each `true` row) and then compare dates to find the number of days between the two to get the count:

```sql
SELECT "date",
       CASE value
       WHEN 'true'
       THEN "date" - LAG( CASE value WHEN 'false' THEN "date" END, 1, "date" )
              IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY "date" ASC )
       ELSE 0
       END as cnt
FROM   table_name
```

The `CASE` expression inside the `LAG` allows `LAG` to only consider the rows that are `false`. When you subtract two dates this will give you the number of days between them; this exactly matches the count that is required given that the rows are consecutive.

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( "date", value ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-15', 'true'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-14', 'true'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-13', 'true'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-12', 'false' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-11', 'true'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-10', 'false' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-09', 'false' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> date      | CNT
> :-------- | --:
> 09-JAN-20 |   0
> 10-JAN-20 |   0
> 11-JAN-20 |   1
> 12-JAN-20 |   0
> 13-JAN-20 |   1
> 14-JAN-20 |   2
> 15-JAN-20 |   3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7a921f4e18c0659267a0181361edff82)*

---

If you have `true` values on the earliest date(s) then you can extend the above query to fix this with:

```sql
SELECT "date",
       CASE value
       WHEN 'true'
       THEN "date"
            - COALESCE(
                LAG( CASE value WHEN 'false' THEN "date" END, 1, NULL )
                  IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY "date" ASC ),
                MIN( "date" ) OVER () - 1
              )
       ELSE 0
       END as cnt
FROM   table_name
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f4654392764c5dc5b0692d7f5f4c4340)

Comment: Nice and compact, though I'm not sure I'd rely on there not being any gaps in the data and/or multiple rows in a single day.  In any case, I think this needs a minor adjustment for cases where the earliest rows are "true".  There is no "false" record for the `LAG` to find.